# How to select an array of specific struct values in hive sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Let's say I have a column containing data in this format inside a table named myTable:

| myColumn |
| --- |
| [{"id": 1, color: "red"}, {"id": 2, color: "blue"}] |
| [{"id": 1, color: "orange"}, {"id": 2, color: "purple"}] |

How do I get extract the colors into an array for each row, in this format?

| result |
| --- |
| [red, blue] |
| [orange, purple] |

What I have tried so far -

```
select arr.color
from myTable as mt
    lateral view outer explode(mt.myColumn) as arr
limit 10;
```

Unfortunately this produces result containing 1 color in each row. How do I create an array for colors in each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `explode` function. You can merely call your desired field directly on your array column:

```sql
SELECT myColumn.color FROM myTable
```